# google spreadsheets/ script to set sharing permission of multiple private google spreadsheets to multiple people

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am having to share 50 private google spreadsheets to 50 different  people. I have had the URLs of those spreadsheets and the emails of those people listed in an other spreadsheet, let's say in Column A (URLs list) and Column B (email lists).

I have tried using script to send those URLs to the listed emails but it does not work, since there is a barrier of sharing permission.

So, I am wondering if there is any scripts to automatically set "Can edit" sharing permission to those emails?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

Using Apps Script, you can share the spreadsheet with other users only if following conditions met.

- You have at least Editor role with permission to share.
- You domain administrator has set policy to share the files with any domain or domains which the user's have.
  Basically, if you can share manually, you can share using Apps Script also. Here is a sample code.You may put this in a loop to iterate over all the email addresses and files which you have.

Use the URL to get the ID of Spreadsheet File

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('YOU_SPREADSHEET_URL_HERE');
var fileId = ss.getId();
```

Share this file to the editor

```
DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).addEditor('EDITOR_EMAIL_ADDRESS_HERE');
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmad for your answer. I am using this script to send email : function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() ;
  var startRow = 2;
  var numRows = 3;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow,1,numRows,3);
  var data = dataRange.getValue();
  for (i in data)   {
   var row = data[i];
   var emailAddress = row[5];
   var message = row[2];
   var subject = "Test";
   
   MailApp.sendEmail( emailAddress, subject, message);  
  } 
}  Could I combine what you suggested into this function? Thank you once again!!

Comment: @Maile Yes, Definitely you can combine with some logic.